# How to trigger an event on specific html element with class in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ecmascript-6, dom-manipulation

I'm trying to refactor my jquery code to vanilla because I want to use js properly. But I'm having a problem. I cannot figure out how for example trigger event only on third element with specific class. Because querySelector always returns the first element with that class for example this is my half finished code

```js
const box = document.querySelector('.media-page--box-container');

$(box).on('mouseenter', () => {
  //  $(this). => select hovered element and do something only on it
  console.log('enter')
}).on('mouseleave', () => {
  console.log('leave')
});
```

```css
.media-page--box-container:not(:first-child){
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="media-page--box-container">
  <div class="media-page--inner-wrapper">
    <div class="media-page--image-wrapper">
      <img class="media-page--image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/212x169">
    </div>
    <div class="media-page--image-title-wrapper">
      <span class="media-page--image-title">Image.jpg</span>
    </div>
    <div class="media-page--download-link-wrapper">
      <a class="media-page--download-link" href="#">Download</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="media-page--box-container">
  <div class="media-page--inner-wrapper">
    <div class="media-page--image-wrapper">
      <img class="media-page--image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/212x169">
    </div>
    <div class="media-page--image-title-wrapper">
      <span class="media-page--image-title">Image.jpg</span>
    </div>
    <div class="media-page--download-link-wrapper">
      <a class="media-page--download-link" href="#">Download</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="media-page--box-container">
  <div class="media-page--inner-wrapper">
    <div class="media-page--image-wrapper">
      <img class="media-page--image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/212x169">
    </div>
    <div class="media-page--image-title-wrapper">
      <span class="media-page--image-title">Image.jpg</span>
    </div>
    <div class="media-page--download-link-wrapper">
      <a class="media-page--download-link" href="#">Download</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="media-page--box-container">
  <div class="media-page--inner-wrapper">
    <div class="media-page--image-wrapper">
      <img class="media-page--image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/212x169">
    </div>
    <div class="media-page--image-title-wrapper">
      <span class="media-page--image-title">Image.jpg</span>
    </div>
    <div class="media-page--download-link-wrapper">
      <a class="media-page--download-link" href="#">Download</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can find example in the snippet

Comment: `querySelectorAll()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the code below if you want to add a listener to one element.

```js
const box = document.querySelector('.media-page--box-container');

box.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("Clicked!");
});
```

```html
<div class="media-page--box-container">.media-page--box-container</div>
```

Or this code for few elements

```js
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.media-page--box-container');

boxes.forEach(function(box){
  box.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("Clicked!");
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="media-page--box-container">.media-page--box-container 1</div>
<div class="media-page--box-container">.media-page--box-container 2</div>
<div class="media-page--box-container">.media-page--box-container 3</div>
```

**querySelector** returns one object, **querySelectorAll** and **getElementsByClassName** return array of objects. Not **getElementsByClassName** require class name, not selector in parameters.

```js
console.log("querySelector", document.querySelector('.media-page--box-container'));
console.log("querySelectorAll", document.querySelectorAll('.media-page--box-container'));
console.log("getElementsByClassName", document.getElementsByClassName('media-page--box-container'));
```

```html
<div class="media-page--box-container">.media-page--box-container 1</div>
<div class="media-page--box-container">.media-page--box-container 2</div>
<div class="media-page--box-container">.media-page--box-container 3</div>
```

Note, if there will be no elements on the page, methods will return null. So, you should check this case. If **box** will null, the code will break with an error.

```js
const box = document.querySelector('.media-page--box-container');
console.log("box value", box);

// Wrong:
box.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log("Clicked!");
});

// Correct:
if (box !== null)
  box.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("Clicked!");
  });
```

```html
<div class="media-page--box-container-A">.media-page--box-container-A</div>
<div class="media-page--box-container-B">.media-page--box-container-B</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer should highlight a few things. You may need to handle event bubbling differently. I added e.target to the hover message. Your target is a block element that will trigger the mouse events even where you can't see it so I highlighted it in red. querySelectorAll will grab all elements not just the first one the way querySelector works.

```js
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.media-page--box-container');

boxes[2].addEventListener("mouseover", myMouseover );
boxes[2].addEventListener("mouseleave", myMouseout);

function myMouseover(e) {
  console.log('enter' + e.target);
}

function myMouseout() {
  console.log('leave');
}
```

```css
.media-page--box-container:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.media-page--box-container {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="media-page--box-container">
  <div class="media-page--inner-wrapper">
    <div class="media-page--image-wrapper">
      <img class="media-page--image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/212x169">
    </div>
    <div class="media-page--image-title-wrapper">
      <span class="media-page--image-title">Image.jpg</span>
    </div>
    <div class="media-page--download-link-wrapper">
      <a class="media-page--download-link" href="#">Download</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="media-page--box-container">
  <div class="media-page--inner-wrapper">
    <div class="media-page--image-wrapper">
      <img class="media-page--image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/212x169">
    </div>
    <div class="media-page--image-title-wrapper">
      <span class="media-page--image-title">Image.jpg</span>
    </div>
    <div class="media-page--download-link-wrapper">
      <a class="media-page--download-link" href="#">Download</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="media-page--box-container">
  <div class="media-page--inner-wrapper">
    <div class="media-page--image-wrapper">
      <img class="media-page--image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/212x169">
    </div>
    <div class="media-page--image-title-wrapper">
      <span class="media-page--image-title">Image.jpg</span>
    </div>
    <div class="media-page--download-link-wrapper">
      <a class="media-page--download-link" href="#">Download</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="media-page--box-container">
  <div class="media-page--inner-wrapper">
    <div class="media-page--image-wrapper">
      <img class="media-page--image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/212x169">
    </div>
    <div class="media-page--image-title-wrapper">
      <span class="media-page--image-title">Image.jpg</span>
    </div>
    <div class="media-page--download-link-wrapper">
      <a class="media-page--download-link" href="#">Download</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use querySelectorAll to retrieve all nodes matching your selector.

Because it returns a NodeList, which is an array-like object, you can traverse that by invoking array.prototype.foreach and passing through the nodelist.

From there you can add event listeners to each item in the node list, or any individual node based on the iterator.

```js
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.media-page--box-container');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(boxes, (box, i) => {
    if (i===2) {
        box.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
            console.log('enter')
        });
        box.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
            console.log('leave')
        });
    }
});
```

```css
.media-page--box-container:not(:first-child){
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="media-page--box-container">
  <div class="media-page--inner-wrapper">
    <div class="media-page--image-wrapper">
      <img class="media-page--image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/212x169">
    </div>
    <div class="media-page--image-title-wrapper">
      <span class="media-page--image-title">Image.jpg</span>
    </div>
    <div class="media-page--download-link-wrapper">
      <a class="media-page--download-link" href="#">Download</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="media-page--box-container">
  <div class="media-page--inner-wrapper">
    <div class="media-page--image-wrapper">
      <img class="media-page--image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/212x169">
    </div>
    <div class="media-page--image-title-wrapper">
      <span class="media-page--image-title">Image.jpg</span>
    </div>
    <div class="media-page--download-link-wrapper">
      <a class="media-page--download-link" href="#">Download</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="media-page--box-container">
  <div class="media-page--inner-wrapper">
    <div class="media-page--image-wrapper">
      <img class="media-page--image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/212x169">
    </div>
    <div class="media-page--image-title-wrapper">
      <span class="media-page--image-title">Image.jpg</span>
    </div>
    <div class="media-page--download-link-wrapper">
      <a class="media-page--download-link" href="#">Download</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="media-page--box-container">
  <div class="media-page--inner-wrapper">
    <div class="media-page--image-wrapper">
      <img class="media-page--image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/212x169">
    </div>
    <div class="media-page--image-title-wrapper">
      <span class="media-page--image-title">Image.jpg</span>
    </div>
    <div class="media-page--download-link-wrapper">
      <a class="media-page--download-link" href="#">Download</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```